# Three.js ctm loader issue of creating a parallel .js file for the .ctm file's reference

Tags: javascript, three.js

While working with CTM loader the function requires a .ctm file of object and one .js file, I am able of creating .ctm file of object but I am not able of creating a .js ref file for it in same manner like three.js [example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ctm_materials) file is using it. Can any body help me on this issue? Or if I am making some wrong understanding from the example plz! guide.

Comment: I don't know either, how the js file is created. But it seems to be only necessary for multi material objects. If you have only one material per ctm file, you should stick to this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ctm

Comment: Hey Brakebein, 
Thanks for your reply, but if you will see the example the model is using different materials for different parts of the car, suppose I have to put in  a different car in the same example, I am able of deducing the .ctm file for the obj of the new car, but finding it messy to create the ref .js file, can you guide me with some better approach.

Comment: I'm sorry. I only experienced ctm files with no or just a simple material. Until now I didn't need to handle multi material objects with ctm. But I would like to know as well, how the js file is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that .ctm file is actually made of multiple .ctm files and combined using the join_ctm.py script (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/utils/converters/ctm/join_ctm.py). This scripts outputs the .js file which then tells the CTMLoader how to load each of the parts back out again. (It's actually just JSON describing the offset to each of the concatenated .ctm files)