# How to apply texture to an openctm model converted from obj in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an obj model which includes complete `.obj`, `.mtl` and `.jpg` files.

In order to reduce the loading time in three.js, I tried to convert the .obj file to `.ctm` format by using the ctmconv tool.

Problem is I can't find any documentation to explain how to apply the texture which is the `.jpg` file to the model.

This produces a serious problem on my ongoing project.

Can someone post a link from which I can have some reference to approach my goal?

Comment: [This example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ctm_materials) uses a json file that defines which textures/materials to put on which parts of the model. However, nobody seems to know, how to generate this json file. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673495/three-js-ctm-loader-issue-of-creating-a-parallel-js-file-for-the-ctm-files-re

Comment: I read the code and the json file looks like to indicate the segments in the openctm model since the number of vertices exceeds 65k (heard that 65k is the some kind of limitation of openctm model. Is there any way to use mtlloader and other functional liberaries of three.js to apply the texture?

Comment: @ Brakebein, A shot has been made through three.js editor, that seems be able to generate the corresponding json, not sure.  I have also post similar topic in draco forum in github, an expert from draco side shared an idea to use mtlloader and other functional liberaries to achieve that but without specifying any detail or reference. That still remains puzzle to me. As you can see, my only purpose is to compress the size of the model to optimize the loading time and bandwith consumption plus a little bit security concern.

Comment: @ Brakebein, as you metioned you don't need to create .js for applying multi-material on a ctm model, I have exactly the same requirement to apply just one .jpg which is corresponding to the original .obj model on the ctm model. Could u please help a little more to light me on the subject. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Currently, I'm using a database where I store the reference to the ctm file and corresponding material attributes like color or path to texture file. But using [MTLLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Examples/Loaders/MTLLoader) is indeed an option. As there isn't a combined loader (like OBJMTLLoader), you would need to load ctm and mtl file separatly from each other, and apply the material manually: `new THREE.Mesh( ctm_geometry, mtl_material )`. (I havn't used yet the MTLLoader for myself.)